# Gridview does not view the results in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, database, gridview

I am trying to show the search results on a gridview on the same search page in asp.net. Here is the UI:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    searchResults.DataBind();

}
protected void BClassSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // if (!IsPostBack)
    //{
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = Userfunctions.GetConnectionString();
        con.Open();
        string selected = lbCourseListBox.SelectedValue;

       if(selected!="" && Tcoursenumber.Text!="")
       {
           string query = "select [CRN],[CourseCode],[CourseNumber],[Credit],[CourseName],[Capacity],[InstructorName] from CourseTable where CourseCode='" + lbCourseListBox.SelectedValue+"' and CourseNumber = '" + Tcoursenumber.Text+"'";

            SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);

            DataTable tab = new DataTable();

            adap.Fill(tab);

            searchResults.DataSource = tab;
            searchResults.DataBind();
       }
       else if (selected != "" && Tcoursenumber.Text == "")
       {
           string query = "select [CRN],[CourseCode],[CourseNumber],[Credit],[CourseName],[Capacity],[InstructorName] from CourseTable where CourseCode='" + lbCourseListBox.SelectedValue;

           SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);

           DataTable tab = new DataTable();

           adap.Fill(tab);

           searchResults.DataSource = tab;
           searchResults.DataBind();
       }
       else if (selected == "" && Tcoursenumber.Text != "")
       {
           string query = "select [CRN],[CourseCode],[CourseNumber],[Credit],[CourseName],[Capacity],[InstructorName] from CourseTable where CourseNumber='" + Tcoursenumber.Text;

           SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);

           DataTable tab = new DataTable();

           adap.Fill(tab);

           searchResults.DataSource = tab;
           searchResults.DataBind();
       }
    //}
    Response.Redirect("SearchCourse.aspx");
}
```

The problem is, no search result is displayed in gridview. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `Response.Redirect("SearchCourse.aspx");` at the end of button click

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // do you want to bind something in first time load? then load it here 
        // searchResults.DataSource = tab;
        searchResults.DataBind();

     }

}
```

You don't want to call the  `Response.Redirect` to the same page because when you click on button it will postback the page. if you call `Response.Redirect` it will load new page and you will lost all the control states in the page.

Comment: That works, thanks. But i do not understand why does it work now, what is the difference between my code and your solution?

Comment: @bigO `Response.Redirect` will load your page again. you will lost search selection etc..